# MySQLi::bind_parameter() and MySQLi:fetch() - Performance conundrum

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization, mysqli

I'm working on a small pet project which hopefully will clarify some concerns for me regarding REST backends in PHP. I started the project to focus on building a really simple but efficient backend for a dummy application for iOS, but the essence of it will be reused in a much larger scaled project where I really can't play around testing new techniques.

The question is: Which of the two following algorithms for doing the exactly same thing is preferable in regards to system performance, CPU load, memory consumption etc. Even a tiny difference will multiply with high concurrency use, so I am really concerned about tweaking everything the best way I can in my code. What I cannot touch is the architecture, LEMP (Linux  Nginx MySQL and PHP).

```
$stmt->bind_result($party["title"],
                    $party["description"],
                    $party["latitude"],
                    $party["longitude"],
                    $party["start"],
                    $party["stop"],
                    $party["created"],
                    $party["updated"],
                    $party["displayname"],
                    $party["rating"],
                    $party["rate_count"]
                );

while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
    $parties[] = $party;
}
```

**OR**

```
$stmt->bind_result($title,
                    $description,
                    $latitude,
                    $longitude,
                    $start,
                    $stop,
                    $created,
                    $updated,
                    $displayname,
                    $rating,
                    $rate_count
                );
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
    $len = sizeof($parties);
    $parties[$len]["title"] = $title;
    $parties[$len]["description"] = $description;
    $parties[$len]["latitude"] = $latitude;
    $parties[$len]["longitude"] = $longitude;
    $parties[$len]["start"] = $start;
    $parties[$len]["stop"] = $stop;
    $parties[$len]["created"] = $created;
    $parties[$len]["updated"] = $updated;
    $parties[$len]["displayname"] = $displayname;
    $parties[$len]["rating"] = $rating;
    $parties[$len]["count"] = $rate_count;
}
```

In the first version I bind the parameters directly in an array trying to save potentially many calls to `sizeof()` as used in the second version. My gut tells me this has to be more efficient than the second version, but I wonder if perhaps system resources are used differently, or if `bind_parameters()` works differently behind the scenes when binding into the array.

I do know that the associative arrays in PHP really are a type of really efficient hash-tables under the hood, but they do require extra memory in regards to simple variables. So I guess the question boils down to pros and cons I haven't mentioned myself and whether the big picture favors using more CPU or a bit more memory.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: The best thing you can do is test both cases and see yourself. But I'd guess they perform the same. Take a look at fetch_assoc, that may perform faster.

Comment: @Paolo Thank you for your tip, but I can't find any `fetch_assoc()` for the prepared statement variant. For security I am using prepared statements so I can use the users input data safely in my queries.

I also have limited resources for testing large scale concurrency, so I was hoping someone perhaps had some experience building large scale robust solutions like App backends for a few 100K or more users.

Comment: fetch_assoc() doesn't require a prepared statement as every row became a key of the passed array with the corresponding value set to the row's content. For testing different algorithms do it locally on your PC o Laptop. Finally, I'd suggest to focus on design an then focus on perfomance spotting critical bottleneck (if any) and optimizing code here. Modern interpreters and DB engines do a lot of optimization under the hood. You may find yourself optimizing code without gaining any improvement.